# How to automatically update UI when items are added to List<>

Tags: wpf, collections

Wihtin my current project I have to add data items to a List<> object. I am using a list due to the fact that it is being derived from an external type and due to how it is being utilized by other applications I do not have the ability to request that the type be changed in the assembly from List to ObservableCollection. So as of right now I am stuck using List<> for my storage collection.  Since List<> does not automatically update the UI when items are add I was wondering how to go about invoking this update? 
thanks in advance

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't provide any notifications when its contents are changed. Unless you have some way of getting those notifications, you're stuck.

If you *do* have a way of getting notified (e.g. via a separate event), then this might be doable -- but it would help to know more about your code. Are you using a ViewModel? Does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: No no view model and as you are aware list does not invoke InotificationProperty or Colleciton changed. I ended up going the route of creating an observable collection to handle the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) out of the List and bind it to the UI element.

Comment: Beat me to it, this is the approach that I use whenever I need to subscribe to list events on my UI etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ViewModel and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, it is as easy as throwing the PropertyChanged event with the name of the List<> property as the propertyName argument.

```
PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

if (handler != null)
{
       var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
       handler(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy this is a great point. With this project I am still working in model view presenter patterns and I am working on getting to the MVVM pattern. This is a great tip and point to reference moving forward.
Thank yoU!